# Store and Display Result as a List in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to get an index and value based pair output in Prolog. Below is my Code:

```
tagit0(L) :-tagit0(L, 1).

tagit0([], _) :- nl.
tagit0([H|T], N) :-
     N1 is N + 1,
     format('tag (~w, ~w), ', [N1, H]),
     tagit0(T, N1).
```

Running this: `?- tagit0([a,b,c],0).`

Gives: `tag (1, a), tag (2, b), tag (3, c),`

But i am looking for some output which is **stored in a List and displayed**
Like:

`L = [tag (1, a), tag (2, b), tag (3, c)]`

Comment: `tagit0(List, Result) :- findall(tag(N,I), nth1(N, List, I), Result).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation:

```
tagit0(L,OutL) :-tagit0(L, 0, OutL).

tagit0([], _,[]).
tagit0([H|T], N,[tag(N1, H)|T1]) :-
     N1 is N + 1,
     tagit0(T, N1,T1).
```

Example:

```
?- tagit0([a,b,c],L).
L = [tag(1, a), tag(2, b), tag(3, c)].
```

Note that in order to store the results in a list and return the list you need to add another parameter as above.

Answer (score 2):

Lists can be quite nicely described by DCGs. As for the calling predicate, I would suggest a name that reflects it's relational nature, say `list_tagged/2`:

```
list_tagged(L,T) :-
   phrase(tagged(L,0),T). % the DCG tagged//2 describes T

tagged([],_) -->          % in the empty list
   [].                    % there's nothing to be tagged
tagged([H|T],N0) -->      % the head of a non-empty list
   {N1 is N0+1},
   [tag(N1,H)],           % is tagged with N1
   tagged(T,N1).          % the tail is tagged as well
```

Your example query yields the desired result:

```
   ?- list_tagged([a,b,c],T).
T = [tag(1,a),tag(2,b),tag(3,c)]
```

Note that the predicate is also working in the other direction:

```
   ?- list_tagged(L,[tag(1,a),tag(2,b),tag(3,c)]).
L = [a,b,c] ? ;
no
```